# How do I use FFmpeg and rav1e to create high quality AV1 files?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, 20.04, transcode, av1

I am currently using Ubuntu Focal Fossa 20.04 LTS and I would like to create high quality AV1 files using FFmpeg and librav1e. I have been spurred along by the [addition](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/commit/d8bf24459b694338de4ceb2a2e6d4d2949d6658d) of rav1e support to FFmpeg as 'librav1e'.

The material that I am interested in working with is given here:

1. [Sintel trailer video](https://media.xiph.org/video/derf/y4m/sintel_trailer_2k_720p24.y4m) (720p uncompressed 1.7GB)
2. [Sintel trailer audio](https://media.xiph.org/sintel/sintel_trailer-audio.flac) (flac 5MB)

It is early days for rav1e support under FFmpeg with not a lot of documentation and published experimentation in place. It would be great to see it all working under an Ubuntu LTS release!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like this goal can be accomplished in 4 *relatively easy* steps, thus allowing Ubuntu Focal Fossa 20.04 LTS to get to grips with AV1 encoding with FFmpeg and rav1e!

**1. Get a recent copy of rust...**

Focal Fossa and rav1e benefit from a newer version of rust so grab a newer copy as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

Follow the defaults (just press 'enter') and then run the following to configure your current shell:

```
source $HOME/.cargo/env
```

to allow instant access to the newest rust and friends. Remember to update this installation from time to time (especially if updating rav1e from this guide) by running:

```
rustup update
```

**2. Install rav1e**

Best to install both the executable (the command `rav1e --fullhelp` will then show options that can be used from within FFmpeg with the `-rav1e-params` option) as well as the libraries that FFmpeg will use to successfully compile and produce librav1e.

First the executable, using a simple copy and paste code block:

```
sudo apt-get install nasm build-essential pkg-config libssl-dev && 
mkdir -pv $HOME/{bin,ffmpeg_sources,ffmpeg_build} && 
cd $HOME/ffmpeg_sources && 
wget https://github.com/xiph/rav1e/archive/refs/tags/v0.6.3.tar.gz && 
tar xvf v0.6.3.tar.gz && cd rav1e-0.6.3 && 
cargo build --release && 
find target -name rav1e -exec install -m 755 {} $HOME/bin \; && 
strip ~/bin/rav1e && \
cd $HOME/ffmpeg_sources && rm -rfv rav1e-0.6.3
```

Next install the `cargo-c` applet as well as the libraries and pkg-config file needed by FFmpeg. First run a *one-off* command to install `cargo-c`:

```
cargo install cargo-c
```

and then compile rav1e *again* using the installed `cargo-c`:

```
cd $HOME/ffmpeg_sources && tar xvf v0.6.3.tar.gz && \
cd rav1e-0.6.3 && \
cargo cinstall --release \
     --prefix=$HOME/ffmpeg_build \
     --libdir=$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib \
     --includedir=$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include
```

Best to then remove the rav1e *shared libraries*, leaving the *static libraries* for FFmpeg to pick up (FFmpeg has a problem with the shared rav1e libraries *in this location* on my system):

```
rm -v $HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/librav1e.so*
```

**3. Install FFmpeg**

Now go to [the FFmpeg trac site](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) and install FFmpeg as instructed, remembering to add:

```
--enable-librav1e
```

to the `./configure` string. Then the hard work is done :)

**4. Run the encoder**

A very reasonable encode can then be run on the test files mentioned in the original question:

```
ffmpeg -i sintel_trailer_2k_720p24.y4m -i sintel_trailer-audio.flac \
       -c:v librav1e -qp 80 -speed 4 \
       -tile-columns 2 -tile-rows 2 \
       -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k \
       sintel_trailer_av1.mp4
```

Things to manipulate here would be:

- `-qp 80`: Uses 'quantizer' mode to encode with a range of 0-255. Smaller values are a higher quality, the default is 100. 80 seems to be the sweet spot for this media clip.
- `-speed 4`: Selects the speed preset (0-10) to encode with, 0 is best quality while 10 is the fastest. This particular setting is a nice compromise between speed and quality on my system (2nd generation Threadripper).
- `-tile-columns 2 -tile-rows 2` Quite decent speed enhancements can be made by manipulating rav1e's [tile based encoding](https://blog.rom1v.com/2019/04/implementing-tile-encoding-in-rav1e/). The example given here splits the encoding *and decoding* into 4 segments and seems a decent choice for the suggested input video, feel free to experiment though..

This encodes at many times the speed that is seen with FFmpeg and libaom-av1 and arguably produces far better quality. Doubtless this encoding string can be further refined and I will do this as rav1e, FFmpeg and AV1 encoding mature...

**5. Gratuitous screenshot**

OK so there is an optional 5th step; taking a screenshot of the completed output file running :)

[image]

**Additional Notes...**

- **[FFmpeg Documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#librav1e)**: The docs on the FFmpeg implementation of encoding with rav1e, this can also be seen by searching the FFmpeg man pages, either `man ffmpeg-all` or `man ffmpeg-codecs`. Remember that native rav1e options can be seen with `rav1e --help` and added into any FFmpeg command line by using the `-rav1e-params` option...

Comment: This is a fantastic writeup. I had to install pkg-config (apt install pkg-config) in addition to get it all working, that was probably already on your system.