# AV1 video from 9gag convert

Tags: 18.04, video, vlc, ffmpeg, av1

Players can't play it, FFmpeg can't convert it

VLC:

```
Codec not supported:
VLC could not decode the format "av01" (AOMedia's AV1 Video)
```

Video:

```
video/x-gst-fourcc-av01 decoder is requiered to play the file, but not installed
```

FFmpeg:

```
admin@admin-ThinkPad-Twist:~$ ffmpeg -i "awo1DPQ_460svav1.mp4" -c:v rawvideo "awo1DPQ_460svav1-s.mp4"
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'awo1DPQ_460svav1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:31.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 88 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: av1 (av01 / 0x31307661), none(progressive), 460x470, 88 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 46:47, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 10240 tbn, 10240 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
File 'awo1DPQ_460svav1-s.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (? (?) -> rawvideo (native))
Decoder (codec av1) not found for input stream #0:0
```

What do I do?

Comment: AV1 playback and encoding is now pretty widespread, in particular FFmpeg and VLC can cope with both. Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @andrew.46 18.03 LTS

Answer (score 4):

The good news is that it is relatively easy to get both playback and encoding with AV1 under Ubuntu 18.04:

1. **Playback**: The repository vlc will not play AV1 files but if you install *the snap version* you will have that capability. Run the following from a Terminal:

   ```
   sudo snap install vlc
   ```

   Currently this will give you vlc 3.0.8 with AV1 playback capability.
2. **Encoding**: There is [a guide on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1189174/57576) which will outfit a recent version of FFmpeg with the ability to encode and decode AV1 files. This is my guide and I have just tested it again *comprehensively* just now and it works beautifully :)

This will give pretty up to date AV1 abilities on Ubuntu 18.04, I add a screenshot of vlc with AV1 playback on my own 18.04 system (the video was one I created myself from the 'Encoding' guide above in point 2):

[image]

It all works nicely on my system and should on yours as well :)